# How To Convert Object to T, and pass T as Func input argument

Tags: c#, list, generics, reflection

I have an operator class that has a func is, if input argument of **Function**(it is a `Func`) was `int`,`float` or `string` I can convert object and call `Func` with `Function(<T>a)`, when `<T>` is a `List`.

How can I convert an `object` **a** to `<T>`? (I know that `<T>` is a `List` of Something):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace GameToolkit.Operator
{
    public abstract class IOperator
    {
        public abstract Type OutputType { get; }
        public abstract Type[] GetInputTypes();
        public abstract object GetValue(object a);
        public ValueToken GetValues(object a)
        {
            var v = GetValue(a);
            return new ValueToken() { Type = v.GetType(), Value = v };
        }
    }
    public class SingleOperand<T, O> : IOperator
    {
        public Func<T, O> Function { get; set; }
        public SingleOperand()
        {
        }
        public SingleOperand(Func<T, O> function)
        {
            Function = function;
        }
        public override object GetValue(object a)
        {
            if (Function == null)
                return default(T);
            if (a.GetType().IsGenericType)
            {
                ///SOME CODE HERE!!!
            }
            else
            return Function((T)a);
        }
        public override Type OutputType => typeof(O);

        public override Type[] GetInputTypes()
        {
            return new[] { typeof(T) };
        }
    }
}
```

For More Detail:

```
    [Test]
    public void UTValueExpressions1()
    {
        var a = new SingleOperand<List<float>, bool>((b)=>{return b.Count > 0;});
        a.GetValue(new List<float>{1,2});
}
    [Test]
    public void UTValueExpressions2()
    {
        var a = new SingleOperand<List<float>, bool>((b)=>{return b.Count > 0;});
        a.GetValue(new List<int>{1,2});
}
    [Test]
    public void UTValueExpressions3()
    {
        var a = new SingleOperand<List<float>, bool>((b)=>{return b.Count > 0;});
        a.GetValue(new List<object>{1,2});
     }
```

the above 3 test only **UTValueExpressions1** pass, i want convert the `List<int>` or `List<object>` to `List<float>` if it can be!

Comment: For the question in the title, you already have `Function((T)a)`` But the question body says something different. And your code says something different again (because you don't check for List at all). Maybe you first want to find out what you really want to know and ask a single question.

Comment: if i send this sample maybe it become clear
SingleOperand  OP = new SingleOperand < List<int>, bool > () {
                                Function = (b0) => {
                                    return b0.Count>0;
                                }
OP.GetValue(new List<int>(){1,2}); // Not Cast
@ThomasWeller

Answer (score 0):

Not diving into WHY do you want that, but for the provided usage:

```cs
var OP = new SingleOperand<List<int>, bool> { Function = b0 => b0.Count > 0 };
object res = OP.GetValue(new List<int> { 1, 2 });
```

For `new SingleOperand<List<int>, bool>` - `T` is a `List<int>` so the same casting approach should apply:

```
public override object GetValue(object a)
{
    if (Function == null)
        return default(T);
        
    return Function((T)a);
}
```

No need for extra generic checks here. Note that this code will throw if `a` is not actually a `T`.

**UPD**

It seems that you have some misconceptions about C# type system and how complex actually is what you are trying to achieve. Your current approach will not work (even if you were able to figure out generics) even for "simple" value types:

```cs
var a = new SingleOperand<float, bool>((b)=> b> 10);
a.GetValue(1);
```

[Demo @sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Could you please edit the question to clarify it as you seem to understand it?

Comment: Please check my editing and test samples @GuruStorn

Comment: @eager in short - do not do this. This is quite complex with a lot of edge-cases and eventually will blow in your face one way or another. Please check out the update.